# Problem with a trigonometric function: $\arctan ( \sin x /(1-\cos x))$

Tags: fourier-series, trigonometric-series

I am studying Abel summability right now, and at a certain point I obtain the following identity:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin kx}{k} r^k = \arctan \frac{r\sin x}{1-r\cos x}
$$
By previous results, we have that the series 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin kx}{k}
$$
converges for all $x\in [0,2\pi ]$, and since Abel summability generalizes convergence, then we have that
$$
\lim_{r\to 1^-}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin kx}{k} r^k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin kx}{k} = \lim_{r\to 1^-} \arctan \frac{r\sin x}{1-r\cos x} =\arctan \frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}.
$$
It is known that for $x\in [0,2\pi]$, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin kx}{k} =(\pi-x)/2$, however I am not able to prove
$$
\arctan \frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}=\frac{\pi - x}{2},
$$
so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try taking derivatives?

Comment: I didn't, but I am going to.

Comment: Try the double-angle formulae for $\sin$ and $\cos$ first.

Comment: Great, just obtained $\arctan \cot x/2$, by the double angle thing, thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2})=\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2})}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2})}=\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}=\frac{2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})}{2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\sin(\frac{x}{2})}=\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}$